# How to capture complement of a grouped regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to detect C like multiline comments using regular expression(the re module in python).

So it should be able to find

```
/* this is my
first comment it also has a * in it.
Now I end my first comment */
int a = 3;

/* this is my second
multiline comment */
```

So I need to find these two multiline comments using a re. I want to do 
    `re.findall(r'exp', string )`. What should be in expression? I tried doing complement of grouped characters like this `r'\(\*[^(?:\*\))]*\*\)` basically grouping *) and checking for its complements. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex? It's so much easier with the `find()` or `partition()` functions of `string`.

Comment: Hi @Steve I am writing a tokenizer which would extract comments as tokens. I think find and partition are not powerful enough.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
import re

ccode = '''/* this is my
first comment it also has a * in it.
Now I end my first comment */
int a = 3;

/* this is my second
multiline comment */'''

for comment in re.findall('/[*].*?[*]/', ccode, re.DOTALL):
    print comment
```

Gives:

```
/* this is my
first comment it also has a * in it.
Now I end my first comment */
/* this is my second
multiline comment */
```

Having said that, if you are building a parser it might be better to first extract tokens in a lexer and define the comments as multi-token constructs in a parser.

Comment: Thanks perreal. This works. I checked it in the sample implementations included with ply. r'/\*(.|\n)*?\*/' also does it :)

Comment: What about this case: /* func(" */abc"); */ ;-)

Comment: @Artur, right, that's why using/writing a parser is a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is not doable just with regexes - you may create state machine as you have to differentiate such cases for example:

- trigraphs
- continued lines
- /* may be found within a string - then it does not start a comment
- on the contrary you may have */ within a string if openin /* was outside a string

You'll NOT do that using regexes. Just state machine.

I know you wanted python but I've done sth similar what you want in erl the other day so her you go. Go ahead and convert to python. Maybe it is not fastest / best but good enough:

```
######################################################################################
#### Before going any further perform all 4 stages of preprocessing
#### described here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html
############################# 1 - break file into lines ##############################

open FILE, $file or die "file [$file] was not found\n";
my @lines = <FILE>; # deletes \r from every line(\n stays on place)
close FILE;

################################ 2 - handle trigraphs ################################
foreach ( @lines )
{
    s!\Q??=\E!#!g;   #??= becomes #
    s#\Q??/\E#\\#g;  #??/ becomes \
    s#\Q??'\E#^#g;   #??' becomes ^
    s#\Q??(\E#[#g;   #??( becomes [
    s#\Q??)\E#]#g;   #??) becomes ]
    s#\Q??!\E#|#g;   #??! becomes |
    s#\Q??<\E#{#g;   #??< becomes {
    s#\Q??>\E#}#g;   #??> becomes }
    s#\Q??-\E#~#g;   #??- becomes ~
}

################################ 3 - merge continued lines ###########################
# everything in C/C++ may be spanned across many lines so we must merge continued
# lines to handle things correctly
# we do not delete lines that are merged with preceeding line - we just leave an
# empty line to preserve overal location of all things which will be needed later
# to properly report line numbers if we find sth that we are intersted in

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#lines; $i++ )
{
    # shows where continued line started ie. where to append following continued line(s)
    state $appendHere; # acts also as an "append indicator"
    my $continuedLine;

    # theoretically continued line ends with \ but preprocessors accept \ followed by
    # one or more whitespaces too so we accept it as well
    if ( $lines[$i] =~ m#\\[ \t\v\f]*$# ) # merge with next line / continued line ?
    {
        $lines[$i] =~ s#\\[ \t\v\f]*$##; # delete \ with trailing whitespaces if any
        $continuedLine =  1;
    }
    else
    {
        $continuedLine =  0;
    }

    if ( !defined $appendHere )
    {
        if ( $continuedLine == 1 )
        {
            # we will append continued lines to $lines[$appendHere]
            $appendHere = $i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        chomp $lines[$appendHere];             # get rid of \n before appending next
        chomp $lines[$i];                      # get rid of \n before appending next
        $lines[$appendHere] .= "$lines[$i]\n"; # append current line to previously marked location
        $lines[$i] = "\n";                     # leave only \n in the current line since we want to preserve line numbers

        if ( $continuedLine == 0 ) # merge next line too?
        {
            $appendHere = undef;
        }
    }
}

#printFileFormatted();

######################## 4 - handle comments and strings  ######################################
# similarly substituting a comment body with a single space may spoil our line numbers so
# we are just replacing comments with spaces preserving newlines where necessary

my $state = "out";
my $error;
my $COMMENT_SUBST = ' '; #'@';
my $STRING_SUBST = ' ';  #'%';

ERROR: for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#lines; $line++ )
{
    state $hexVal = 0;
    state $octVal = 0;
    state $string = "";

    my @chars = split //, $lines[$line];
    my $newLine = "";

    for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#chars; $i++ )
    {
        my $c = $chars[$i];

        if ( $state eq 'out' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c eq '/' )
            {
                $state = 'comment?';
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq '"' )
            {
                $state = 'string char';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            else
            {
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'comment?' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c eq '/' )
            {
                $state = '//comment';
                chop $newLine;
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST x 2;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq '*' )
            {
                $state = '/*comment';
                chop $newLine;
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST x 2;
            }
            else
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq '//comment' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
            else
            {
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq '/*comment' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c eq '*' )
            {
                $state = '/*comment end?';
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
            else
            {
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq '/*comment end?' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c eq '*' )
            {
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $newLine .= $c;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq '/' )
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
            else
            {
                $state = '/*comment';
                $newLine .= $COMMENT_SUBST;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'string char' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            # theoretically ignore "everything" within a string
            # which may look like "abc\\" = abc\   or "abc\"" = abc"
            # "abc\" - wrong - no end of string, "abc\\\" wrong again

            # in order to detect if particular " terminates a string we have to check the whole string
            # since it cannot be determined just by checking what the previous character was hence
            # that state machine was created

            if ( $c eq '"' )
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\\" )
            {
                $state = 'string esc seq';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - a newline within a string\n";
                last ERROR;
            }
            else
            {
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'string esc seq' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            # simple esc seq \' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
            # oct num     \o \oo \ooo no more than 3 oct digits (o=[0-7]{1,3}) but value must be < than 255
            # hex num     \xh \xhh \xhhh..... unlimited number of hex digits (h=[0-9a-fA-F]+) but value must be < than 255

            # in any other esc seq \ will be ignored hence  \u=u  \p=p \k=k etc

            if ( $c =~ m#^['"\?\\abfhrtv]$# )
            {
                $state = 'string char';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST x 2;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq 'x' )
            {
                $state = 'string hex marker';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c =~ m#^[0-7]$#)
            {
                $state = 'string oct';
                $octVal = oct($c);
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - a newline within a string\n";
                last ERROR;
            }
            else # other esc seqences are ignored - usually a warning is issued
            {
                $state = 'string char';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST x 2;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'string hex marker' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c =~ m#^[0-9a-fA-F]$# )
            {
                $state = 'string hex';
                $hexVal = hex($c);
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - hex escape sequence not finished\n";
                last ERROR;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'string hex' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c =~ m#^[0-9a-fA-F]$# )
            {
                $hexVal <<= 4;
                $hexVal += hex($c);

                # treat as regular 8bit character sequence - no fancy long chars etc
                if ( $hexVal > 255 )
                {
                    $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - hex escape sequence too big for a character\n";
                    last ERROR;
                }

                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq '"' )
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
                $hexVal = 0;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - a newline within a string\n";
                last ERROR;
            }
            else
            {
                $state = 'string char';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
                $hexVal = 0;
            }
        }
        elsif ( $state eq 'string oct' ) # ----------------------------------------------
        {
            if ( $c =~ m#^[0-7]$# )
            {
                $octVal <<= 3;
                $octVal += oct($c);

                # treat as regular 8bit character sequence - no fancy long chars etc
                if ( $octVal > 255 )
                {
                    $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - oct esc sequence too big for a character\n";
                    last ERROR;
                }

                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq "\n" )
            {
                $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - a newline within a string\n";
                last ERROR;
            }
            elsif ( $c eq '"' )
            {
                $state = 'out';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
                $octVal = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                $state = 'string char';
                $newLine .= $STRING_SUBST;
                $octVal = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $error = "line [".($line+1)."] - error - state machine problem - unknown state\n";
            last ERROR;
        }

    }#for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#chars; $i++ )

    $lines[ $line ] = $newLine;
}#for ( my $line = 0; $line <= $#lines; $line++ )

if ( $error ) # errors detected within state machine?
{
    print "$error";
    exit(1);
}
else # EOF met - check the state
{
    if ( $state eq 'out' )
    {
        # ok no problem
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'comment?' )
    {
        # ok no problem - may be a division after all - not a preproc problem
    }
    elsif ( $state eq '//comment' )
    {
        # ok no problem
    }
    elsif ( $state eq '/*comment' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within /* */ comment\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq '/*comment end?' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within /* */ comment\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'string char' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within string\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'string esc seq' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within string\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'string hex marker' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within string\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'string hex' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within string\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    elsif ( $state eq 'string oct' )
    {
        print "EOF reached within string\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        print "EOF reached and state machine is in unknown state\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Artur just found it in a sample implementation for ANSI C from ply examples.    r'/\*(.|\n)*?\*/' does it :)

Comment: @noPe: this regex does only fraction of possible cases that m\one may find in a C/C++ file: try this: /* func(" */abc"); */

Answer (score -1):

IF you are writing a tokenizer, and you WILL include checking for string, so your pattern won't match *comment* that is inside a string, then this pattern will work for you:
`"(/[*][\S\s]*?[*]/)"`